# Is onion good with leek?

Tags: food-science, onions, mixing, french-cuisine

I have onions and leek and I want to sautee the two together. Can I use both?

Comment: What are French onions?

Comment: Oh lol ok ahah, my bad, leek and onion I ment. In portuguese leek is 'alho francês', which would translate to 'french garlic', so double fail :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leeks and onions can be cooked together without any problems.

Comment: Does it make sense or just too much acid in the sautee?

Comment: Onions and leeks have approximately the same pH value.